# url dispatcher detect all and nothing with regexp

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am trying to create a URL dispatcher whic detects `[a-zA-Z]` chars (one word) and nothing at all.

I tried something like this, but the nothing does not work, only the chars.

```
url(r'(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z].*?)/?$', 'website.views.index_view', name='website_index'),
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this instead (note the lack of a dot after `[a-zA-Z]`):

```
ur'^(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z]*)/?$'
```

In your original regex, `.*?` will allow for any character(s) (even spaces, for example). Also, `[a-zA-Z]` will only match a single character unless it is followed by an `*` or a `+`.

Here is an example of my regex using the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(ur'^(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z]*)/?$', 'testString/')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02BF4F20>  # matches 'testString/'
>>> re.match(ur'^(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z]*)/?$', 'test-String/')  # does not match 'test-String/' because of the hyphen
>>> re.match(ur'^(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z]*)/?$', '')  # also matches empty string ''
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02BF44A0>
```

Comment: Love your username. But that does not do the trick unfortunately. Still doesnt accept nothing.

Comment: I mislead you with my question, the `or` should ofcourse be `and`, this is a huge typo, i will fix it right away!

Comment: @JavaCake Ah, I see. You also want to accept nothing. I changed the regex above. Specifically, change the `+` to a `*`.

Comment: That was odd. Now my view function does not get the variable `search_word` when typed in the URI.

Comment: Oh wait a minute. Its messing up with Nordic chars. `ÆØÅæøå`

Comment: @JavaCake If unicode characters are giving you trouble, you can try to add a `u` before the `r` like so: `ur'^(?P<search_word>[a-zA-Z]*)/?$'`.

Comment: I added `# -- coding: utf-8 --` to the top of my `urls.py` and changed it to `r'(?P<search_word>[ÆØÅæøåa-zA-Z]*)/?$'`, but it still seems like its ignoring the chars.

Comment: @JavaCake Great! I'm glad to hear it worked for you. I updated my answer above.

Comment: i have another problem. I have a `sitemap.xml` dispatch on the same level of the URI, is there a way to dispatch this simultaneously? Do i need to exclude it first from the first dispatch?

Comment: @JavaCake That is a great question. You should post that question (with the relevant code) in a new question. (It's a bit hard to answer in the comments here without seeing the relevant code, and it will receive a lot of attention as a new question.)

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335622/multiple-url-dispatches-with-regex